# R- Reading excel files with loop and creating data frames

Tags: r, loops, dataframe

I have a bunch of files (number continuously growing),
each file shoud get a seperate data frame.

To simplify the reading I would like to use a Loop to read all files.
The new data frames should be named after a string from "Filename"

In the last row i would like to create an data Frame, the Name of the new data frame should be the Content of "Filename".

```
for(x in 1:nrow(Namen)) # creation of the loop

{

  Filename<- Namen[x,1] #Takes the Filename from the the DF

  einlesepfad <- "path for reading the xlsm files" 
   einlesepfad <- paste(einlesepfad,Filename,".xlsm", sep="") # creation of the path to read the xlsm file
   Filename <- read_excel(einlesepfad) #The Content of "Filename" should be the Name of the new data frame
}
```

Comment: Please clarify your question. Have a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) on how to create a minimal working example.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, you want to read many files from a list into individual data frames? I'm offering a slightly different solution:

```
results <- list()
for(x in 1:nrow(Namen)) # creation of the loop
{
  Filename<- Namen[x,1] #Takes the Filename from the the DF

  einlesepfad <- "path for reading the xlsm files" 
  einlesepfad <- paste(einlesepfad,Filename,".xlsm", sep="") # creation of the path to read the xlsm file
  results[Filename] <- read_excel(einlesepfad) # The list gets a new item, named whatever value Filename had, that contains your data
}
```

This way, each of your files is in a **separate data frame**, and all the data frames are in one list - `results`. To access the data frame from file `"datafile1.xlsm"` do this:

```
results['datafile1']
```

or even

```
results$datafile1
```

What you were trying to do previously was to give a **separate variable** to each data frame - possible (you could construct statements with `paste` and then `eval` them, I think), but a list of dataframes is almost always a better idea.

Comment: I have a bunch of files (number continuously growing),
each file shoud get a seperate data frame.
To simplify the reading I would like to use a Loop to read all files.
The new data frames should be named after a string from "Filename"

Answer (score 0):

Using your packages and example you can do the following:

Pass the filenames in a list:

```
Namen <- list(c('fname1', 'fname2') # your names list (i am guessing without .xlsx)
einlesepfad <- "path for reading the xlsm files"
```

Push each file into a dataframe

```
df.list <- list() #empty data frame list
df.list= lapply(Namen, function(i){
  fname <- paste0(einlesepfad, i, '.xlsm') # get the full filename
  x = read_excel(fname) # read the excel file in
  # Edit: Removed the name column part
  # Return your data
  return (x)
})
```

**Edit:**
Just saw your edit with the request for named list by the elements. Here is a very fast (non-elegant) solution to add the names:

```
names(df.list) <- lapply(Namen, function(x){x})
```

You can then access every dataframe of the list by either
`df.list['name']` or by index `df.list[1]`

**Edit2:**
Also, since i noticed you say your filename list is continuously growing, provided that you store all the files in the same dir you could do the following:

```
Namen <– list.files(einlesepfad, '*.xlsm')
```

and just remember to change the fname inside the function and remove the '.xlsm' part as such:

```
fname <- paste0(einlesepfad, i)
```